# Opensearch - get inner aggregations from aggregations using opensearch-java client

Tags: java, aggregation, opensearch, java-client

There is this opensearch query constructed using openserch-java

```
GET eventsearch/_search
{
  "aggregations": {
    "WEB": {
      "aggregations": {
        "eventDate": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "extended_bounds": {
              "max": "2022-12-01T00:00:00Z",
              "min": "2022-01-01T00:00:00Z"
            },
            "field": "eventDate",
            "fixed_interval": "1d",
            "min_doc_count": 0
          }
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "channel": {
            "value": "WEB",
            "case_insensitive": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "eventDate": {
              "from": "2022-01-01T00:00:00Z",
              "to": "2022-12-01T00:00:00Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Running query, the response is this:

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 26,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "WEB" : {
      "doc_count" : 25,
      "eventDate" : {
        "buckets" : [
          {
            "key_as_string" : "2022-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "key" : 1640995200000,
            "doc_count" : 0
          },
          {
            "key_as_string" : "2022-01-02T00:00:00.000Z",
            "key" : 1641081600000,
            "doc_count" : 0
          },
          {
            "key_as_string" : "2022-01-03T00:00:00.000Z",
            "key" : 1641168000000,
            "doc_count" : 0
          },
          {
            "key_as_string" : "2022-01-04T00:00:00.000Z",
            "key" : 1641254400000,
            "doc_count" : 0
          },
    ....................
            ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In java I need to perform this query and get the results from there.

But after using the `opensearchclient.search` and then get the "aggregations" list method, I receive this (image attached) and get

[image]

If I try to get the "WEB" from the Map, there is no other "eventDate" aggregation to fetch.

Is there a way to fetch this inner aggregation using opensearch-java client? I had no luck with documentation.

opensearch-java 2.1.0

Comment: @VikramSingh The fix was in this PR https://github.com/opensearch-project/opensearch-java/pull/234 and it got merged. So the latest version got it

Comment: Is the fix available in Java Client 2.8.1? Is the fix released? If so, an example of doing the same would be helpful using code.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no feature like this, it exists an open bug, with merged code, but not released.

https://github.com/opensearch-project/opensearch-java/issues/197